# Google Chrome problema com mudar senha

Tags: php, google-chrome

Tenho um `colorbox` na página que faz a mudança de senha do usuário, ele funciona normalmente, porém não sei o por quê as vezes o **Google Chrome** da algum bug e não executa essa mudança, como exemplo testei mudar a senha do mesmo usuário no **Google Chrome** (modo anônimo) e no **Google Chrome Canary** (modo anônimo).

No Canary não executou a mudança, na qual não deu retorno de mensagem de ok ou erro, já no Google Chrome alterou.

As vezes a limpeza de cache em outras máquinas que também dão esse problema, resolve, porém não é sempre, além de que o usuário ter que ficar limpando a todo momento o cache é algo degradante.

**Script do `colorbox`:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $("form[name='formulario']").validate({
        // Especifica as regras da validação
        rules: {
            senha_1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            senha_2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#senha_1"
            }                   
        },
        messages: {
            senha_1: {
                required: "<?=TXT_VALIDATE_MSG_SENHA?>",
                minlength: "<?=TXT_VALIDATE_MSG_SENHA?>"
            },
            senha_2: {
                required: "<?=TXT_VALIDATE_MSG_REPITASENHA?>",
                minlength: "<?=TXT_VALIDATE_MSG_REPITASENHA?>",
                equalTo: "<?=TXT_VALIDATE_MSG_SENHA_DIFERENTE?>"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
            parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); 
            parent.location = parent.location;
        }
    });
});
```

**Parte de POST e SESSION que é executado no submit**

```
    $idProprietario = Entrada::Int('id');
$nome = Entrada::String('nm');
$email = Entrada::String('email');
$senha = Entrada::String('senha_1');
////////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////////////
//                 UPDATE                 //
if ($conexao->consulta("UPDATE proprietario SET senha = '".base64_encode($senha)."' WHERE idProprietario=".$idProprietario)) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "ok|".TXT_ACAO_ADMIN_SENHA_ALTERADA;
} else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "erro|".TXT_ACAO_CADASTRO_ERRO_SQL;  
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código, se possível alguma imagem do erro, fica mais claro de conseguir entender o problema.

Comment: Coloquei o código

Comment: Esse erro costuma acontecer após algum tipo de alteração no `js`?

Comment: Alterei para você ver nesse caso específico no que eu estava mexendo, esse erro ele da de uma forma muito aleatória, as vezes fechando o navegador e abrindo de novo da certo ou entrando em outra janela. Não sei como o erro é gerado. A única coisa que consegui verificar é que quando não da certo tanto a mensagem de OK quanto de ERRO não aparecem.

Comment: Essas funções js você chama ela em que parte da pagina ? no `header` ou abaixo do `body`?

Comment: É o seguinte, tem uma página que mostra os usuário linkados à aquele loguin, e na frente de cada usuário tem um ícone de mudança de senha que abre o modal do colorbox, a chamada é dentro da tag **tbody** que tem um link de ref na qual leva para um outro .php